# Android Javascript function only works on initial load

Tags: javascript, java, android

In my Android Application, I have a WebView, before it displays anything from it though, I made it so that certain elements on my site do not display with javascript.It however only works on the first load, if you actually navigate through the site(click on a post for example) it will display all of the elements I don't want it to. It was working perfectly fine before, and now I cannot figure out why it isn't working. I'd appreciate any help!

```
mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(final WebView view, final String url, final Bitmap favicon) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
        {
            mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-youtube')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('fa fa-twitter')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('menu-primary-container')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('menu-toggle')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "document.getElementsByClassName('widget_slider_area')[0].style.display='none'; " +
                    "})()");
            bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com");
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `alert()`s or `console.log()`s  between the `document.getElementsByClassName...` lines? I would be curious if there is some issue in there where maybe the first `getElements...` call is returning an empty results, and then because you are accessing the index without checking the return, it is throwing an error. Adding some kind of debug notification/print statement there should help with identifying that issue (if it is happening). Also, have you tried executing the script using `mWebView.getEngine().executeScript(...)`? I'm not sure, but that may make a difference.

Comment: I'll look into it, and try 'mWebView.getEngine().executeScript(...)', thank you for your time